# Get spoken Language from Yahoo

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-api

How can I get the spoken language of a country using YQL?

My approach was:

```
select lang from geo.countries where name ="Italy"
```

But I always get English as language:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2015-12-27T23:43:58Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "url": {
    "execution-start-time": "28",
    "execution-stop-time": "98",
    "execution-time": "70",
    "content": "http://wws.geotech.yahooapis.com/v1/countries;start=0;count=1000"
   },
   "user-time": "103",
   "service-time": "70",
   "build-version": "0.2.369"
  },
  "results": {
   "place": {
    "lang": "en-US" // wrong language!
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Here you can play around with the YQL console: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+lang+from+geo.countries+where+name+%3D%22Italy%22

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/api_docs.html), `lang` is not the spoken language.

In the `header` section is used to identify the language in the request response.

In `results`, it's used to identify which language was used to describe the localized name of the place.

I'm afraid that GeoPlanet API will **not** return info like spoken language, currency, etc. Its focus is on geo location (coordinates, states, counties, etc) and provide the place names in several languages.